# Encoding error in urlparameters in aws lambda using api gateway and proxy integration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When calling my lambda function with a url parameter containing a special character, the text turns from `hindbærsnitter` to `hindb￦rsnitter`.

I call it like this:

```
/prod/search/hindbærsnitter
```

Is this an error in apigateway/lambda or can i fix it in my own code?

It seems like an encoding error, and i tried to set `charset=UTF-8` in the request, but to no avail.

Comment: did you try with something like this ` -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' `

Comment: Yes, it did not work however

Comment: Curiously, the last octet of url-escaped utf-8 encoding for these characters is the same: æ is `%C3%A6` while ￦ is `%EF%BF%A6`... so it shouldn't be a classic double-encoding, because it wouldn have at least 4 octets. Is this the path or a query string parameter?

Comment: It is the path parameter

Comment: Did you see `æ` or `￦` in API Gateway's CloudWatch log?